# Confused about the direction

Tags: electromagnetism

I am reading electromagnetism. And while finding the boundary conditions, the author has written that the cross product has been chosen according to the right hand convention.
Now what does it means, I am unable to comprehend that 
Can anyone help.
[image]

Comment: Do you know what the right hand rule is?

Comment: What I believe it to be is that the direction your thumb point towards, when you curl your fingers in the direction of the two vectors you want to have a cross product of, gives the direction of their cross product vector.

Comment: *curl the fingers of your right hand.

Comment: Do you know what it represents and mean in this context?

Comment: I think no. That is why I am confused. Help.

Comment: Google is your friend. Or your physics teacher.

Comment: Who is begging ?

Answer (score 3):

Ampère's rule is the one you describe, as shown:

[image: Ampère's rule]

But for the cross product you need to use the thumb, first finger and second finger as shown:

[image: cross product]

Both images come from this source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule